# List Item gets altered

Tags: c#, list, storage, ram

I am pretty sure that somewhere this question was answered but i could not find it.

I am looking up Objects from a list with name and quantity. The same Item can come up several times with different quantities. I want to add up the quantities.

```
bool addtolist = true; //the item is not part of the list
Item currentItem = FindItem(currentMats.Name); //Find the Item in the Catalogue
currentItem.Calc(currentMats.NeededQuantity, product.Runns, product.Level + 1); //Add quantities ect
CompleteList.Add(currentItem);
```

Here is the problem:
The first time the Algorithm runs all is ok.
The Problem comes up at the second run: the quantity is overridden the moment it hits line 2.
How can i force a new object and not a reference to the one in the storage?

Comment: I can't find the part of your code that modifies anything called "quantity"

Comment: Where is the definition of the items? Is it a class or a struct? What does `Calc()` do? It is hard to answer this question that is so vague.

Answer (score 1):

A new instance of an object is only created when the `new` keyword is used. To get a copy, you'll have to create one

You could create a copy constructor and then a clone method on Item

```
public Item(Item otherItem){
   variable1 = otherItem.variable1;
   variable2 = otherItem.variable2;
   ...
}

public Item Clone(){
   return new Item(this);
}
```

Then when you get the item, clone it

```
bool addtolist = true; //the item is not part of the list
Item currentItem = FindItem(currentMats.Name).Clone(); //Find the Item in the Catalogue
currentItem.Calc(currentMats.NeededQuantity, product.Runns, product.Level + 1); //Add quantities ect
CompleteList.Add(currentItem);`
```

Comment: A better way to right this would be to use a copy constructor.

`public Item(Item clone){
   this.variable1 = clone.variable1;
   this.variable2 = clone.variable2;
}`

Comment: noted and changed.

Comment: So this is part of the Item file right? i have to copy every property?

Comment: thanks guys i fixed the problem now it works! thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad it's working. Please remember to mark an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are doing is a histogram. LINQ has a built in method called `GroupBy()` that does this. See sample code below:

```
public class Material
{
    public Material(string name, int quantity)
    {
        this.Name=name;
        this.Quantity=quantity;
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Material> list=new List<Material>();
        list.Add(new Material("AAA", 10));
        list.Add(new Material("BBB", 20));
        list.Add(new Material("CCC", 5));
        list.Add(new Material("AAA", 5));
        list.Add(new Material("CCC", 20));

        Console.WriteLine("{0,6} {1,6}", "Mat", "Qty");
        foreach(var item in list.GroupBy((mat) => mat.Name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,6} {1,6}", item.Key, item.Sum((mat) => mat.Quantity));
        }
        //   Mat    Qty
        //   AAA     15
        //   BBB     20
        //   CCC     25

    }
}
```